# How can I Import a *.so file into a *.jar while using Maven build tools?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dynamic-library

How can I Import a *.so file into a *.jar while using Maven build tools? And could load that *.so file?

**considering convenience of the deployment usage.**

I want to load native methods from *.so then run business code... When I packaged jar file and run the app by shell automaticly. But it didn't work in linux.

```
java -jar demo.jar -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dspring.profiles.active=prod

System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

It can load the dll file in the WINDOS's development successfully。

`
//Windows

```
ClassLoader cl = SyWorkflowController.class.getClassLoader();

URL url = cl.getResource("//");

String path = url.getPath();

System.load(path+"mylib.dll");
```

`

**But in the Linux is error (deployment usage).
when using the packaged jar file, can not found the URL.
I found the JVM OPTS 'java.class.path' only represented 'demo.jar'.**

`
//Linux

```
ClassLoader cl = SyWorkflowController.class.getClassLoader();

URL url = cl.getResource("//");   //url is null. occur an error

String path = url.getPath();

System.load(path+"mylib.so");
```

`

When I realsed a demo.jar project and use java cli to run the demo application,
I found the JVM OPTS 'java.class.path' only represented 'demo.jar'.

I tried to package my *.so file into the demo.jar (path:\BOOT-INF\lib) manually and run the application again.
However fails again.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/libmylib.so`

Comment: A Spring Boot Applikcation is not creating a usual JAR file... it has a boot strap part and parts which are in `BOOT-INF` etc. The question is why you need an so/dll ?

Comment: I want to load native methods from so/dll then run business code...
Considering convenience of deployment usage，When I packaged jar file and run the app by shell automaticly.
But it didn't work in linux.

Comment: You should check the spring docs because startup is something different which means the loading should be done in a appllicationready event or alike..

Comment: The so-loader cannot load from inside jar files.  Hence you must unpack it before you run the code needing it.